# Populate and Edit NSView content

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I'm trying to build an application which is listing informations by populating a `NSView`.

For now, I've created an Array `Infos` that contains all my infos.
Then, I use a "for statement" to expand the `mainView` for each Infos and create a Label which have a string value equals to : `Infos[i]`. This way it displays each infos correctly.

This is my code :

```
    for i in 0 ..< Infos.count {

        expandTheMainView()


        var infoLabel: NSTextField!
        deviceBatteryPercentageView = NSTextField(frame: CGRect(x: 250, y: 40+CGFloat(newHeight)-CGFloat(height), width: 37, height: 17))
        infoLabel.stringValue = "\(Infos[i])%"
        infoLabel.editable = false
        infoLabel.bordered = false
        infoLabel.backgroundColor = NSColor(white: 0, alpha: 0)
        mainView.addSubview(infoLabel)

    }
```

However I can not edit them because they are in a "for statement", is there a way to "populate" my view with the possibility to programmatically edit the created infos?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean under "edit" here ?

Comment: I mean edit like the string value of one of the infoLabel whenever I need it.

Comment: What about `infoLabel.editable = true`?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not clear but I want to edit it programatically.

Comment: Add the labels to an array and refer to them by index

Comment: Clever, but it does not modify the view directly. It does modify the value in the array but in the view it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe because you should set  `infoLabel.editable = true` first ? Then you can set it to false back. I mean you can do it thru array references

Comment: Forget the `.editable = true` because it has nothing to do with what I want. This .editable is made to set the NSTextField like a Label because a NSTextField is editable by the user in the interface. Search with google you will better understand ;)

Comment: Sorry, I cannot check the snippet now to find out why your fields won't change  their values, but adding controls to an array for manipulating is a common approach, it should work. Agree with @vadian.

Comment: @vadian answers works ! Thank you everyone !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a tag to each text field in the repeat loop for example

```
infoLabel.tag = i + 100
```

then you can refer to a text field with

```
let thirdTextField = mainView.viewWithTag(102) as! NSTextField
```

and change the value.